# indexOf array of dates "dd.MM.yyyy"

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I need to get the indices of a specific date in an array of more than 10,000 dates. In order to quickly find rows where this date is contained. I used `.getDisplayValues()`, in the logs I see that everything is ok. What am I doing wrong? If you know a faster way, I will be grateful for your advice!

```
function indexOf() {
    var timezone = "GMT+3";
    var date_format = "dd.MM.yyyy";

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getActiveRange().getValue()), timezone, date_format);
    var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
    var data = range.getDisplayValues();

    Logger.log(data);
    Logger.log('date:' + date);

    var indices = [];
    var idx = data.indexOf(date);

    while (idx != -1) {
        indices.push(idx);
        idx = data.indexOf(date, idx + 1);
    }

    Logger.log(indices);
}
```

Sheet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/106u0NOHY3TxHP-34t_p9C_a8DfphaokZXfOl_Wtjlqg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the error/incorrect result you are getting?

Comment: Hi, i am getting empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to search for a specific date, you could use a function which takes a string date as argument in the format of `"dd.MM.YY"`. I am not sure why you were converting the dates to a Date object, but if you just need to find the date indices/row number, you won't need to.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function rowOfDate(date) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A:A')
  var vals = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    var row;
    for (var j = 0; j < vals[i].length; j++) {     
      if (vals[i][j] == date) {
        row = vals[i][j+1];
        var rowNum = i+1;
        var index = i;
        Logger.log(rowNum); 
      }
    }    
  }  
}
```

And just call it like this:

```js
rowOfDate("03.03.2021")
```

The above works by manually specifying a date.

Or:

```js
var dt = sheet.getActiveRange().getDisplayValue();
rowOfDate(dt)
```

The above will take as input the value of the currently selected cell.

The function will print the `rowNumber` of the matched dates, but you can quickly change it to output the index by modifying the `Logger.log()` to:

```js
Logger.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found `getTime` as the best condition cast for js Date for me.

The next sample works fine

> You have to set an active cell one of `A:A`

```js
function indexOf2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var date = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue().getTime();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  var data = range.getValues()
    .findIndex(row => row[0].getTime && date === row[0].getTime())
  console.log(data);
}
```

[image]